# Sum of the numbers between 1 to 100 by atmel studio

Tags: assembly, atmega, atmelstudio

I'm a newbish collegian. I have a task that sum 1 to 100 to r16:r17
so it has to be r16= 0xba, r17=0x13

here's my code

```
ldi xl, 0x00;
ldi xh, 0x01;

ldi r18, 100;

loop1:

add xl, r18;
dec r18;


brne loop1;

mov r16, r26;
mov r17, r27;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rV1i.png)

I don't know what to do now...

Answer (score 1):

You never add anything to `xh` when the addition to `xl` results in a carry. After `add xl, r18;` you need something like:

```
adc xh, r19;
```

Where `r19` is some available register, whose value you have set to 0 before the loop.

---

The fact that you initialize `xh` to 1 also seems a bit strange. An initial value of 0 would make a lot more sense.

Comment: It does really work! Thank you very much!!!